# How is this function that creates a linked list for any environment string supposed to work?

Tags: c, linked-list, environment-variables, token

The code is the following:

```
typedef struct Node
{
    char *str;
    struct Node *next;

} Node;

Node *_getdir(char *path, char **pathCopy)
{
    char *token = NULL;
    Node *head;
    Node *pathNode;


if (path == NULL)
    return (NULL);

*pathCopy = strdup(path); 

head = NULL;
pathNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
if (pathNode == NULL)
    return (NULL);

token = strtok(*pathCopy,  ":");
pathNode->str = token;
pathNode->next = head;
head = pathNode;
while (token != NULL)
{
    token = strtok(NULL, ":");
    if (token == NULL) 
        break;
    pathNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (pathNode == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    pathNode->str = token;
    pathNode->next = head;
    head = pathNode;
}
return (head);

}
path = "/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"
char *pathCopy = NULL;
pathDirs = _getdir(path, pathCopy);
```

My confusion starts at `pathNode = malloc(sizeof(Node))` and finishes at `return (head);`

**First**, I don't understand why this function is allocating the size of a type variable called "Node", storing that information in a variable called pathNode, and just right after that there's an `if statement` to execute in case pathNode is a NULL value, I mean, *how could that be possible if the "Node" type variable is fixed (at least initially)*?

**Second**, I understand that the `strtok` function is used to divide a string by using a delimiter, which in this case is `:`. I also know that the arrow operator `->` is used to access elements in Structures.

But then, the next lines of code are `pathNode->str = token;` and `pathNode->next = head;` which are like, some kind of *variable declaration reversed*, making the syntax look just weird to me, and these variables `str` and `next` were not declared as the case with pointers, isn't that necessary?

And **finally**, there's the while loop, which I guess it's going to be executed until it finds the `\0` element at the end of the `pathCopy` string. However, there's again the use of `pathNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));` , `pathNode->str = token;` and `pathNode->next = head;`, throwing me back to the previous confusion...

Comment: For the first question, malloc can return NULL so it's a valid check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be about single-linked list. This function inserts nodes in to single-linked list.

It allocates `pathNode`, assigns it as `head`.

`strtok` breaks the strings in to tokens, the first token is for `head`.

If the next token is successful, it allocates another node, that node becomes the new `head`. `pathNode->next = head` indicates that the next element is head. It then assigns `head = pathNode`, and continues in the loop.

> *"pathNode is a NULL value, I mean, how could that be possible if the "Node" type variable is fixed (at least initially)"*

`pathNode` can be `NULL` if there is not enough memory and `malloc` fails.

> *"However, there's again the use of pathNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));"*

There is a `malloc` at the beginning for `head` and `malloc` inside the loop for the following nodes.

Also, there a couple of problems. The function uses `pathCopy` to duplicate the source string. This is the right approach because `strtok` will modify its source. But `pathCopy` should be freed at the end. It is of little use to return it to the caller.

Overall this function is more complicated than it needs to be. Here is a simpler example:

```
Node* create_node(const char* str)
{
    Node* node = malloc(sizeof(Node)); if (!node) return NULL;
    node->str = strdup(str);
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

Node* mygetdir(const char* source)
{
    if (!source) return NULL;
    char *path = strdup(source);
    if (!path) return NULL;

    Node* head = NULL;
    char* token = strtok(path, ":");
    while (token)
    {
        Node* save = head;
        head = create_node(token); if (!head) return NULL;
        head->next = save;
        token = strtok(NULL, ":");
    }

    free(path);
    return head;
}
```

You can print it as follows. You have to free the linked list at the end.

```
int main(void)
{
    Node* head = mygetdir("/sbin1:/usr/sbin2:/bin3:/usr/bin4:/usr/local/bin5");
    Node* node = head;
    while (node)
    {
        printf("ID = %s\n", node->str);
        node = node->next;
    }

    node = head;
    while (node)
    {
        Node* next = node->next;

        // ******* EDIT
        // don't call `free(node->str)` if using your own version
        // because in your own version node->str is just a pointer to `pathCopy`
        free(node->str);

        free(node);
        node = next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you sir! Your explanation was very useful, I think I got it now!. 
Btw, when you say that ```pathCopy``` should be freed at the end, can't I just type ```free(pathCopy)``` right after ```return(head)``` in the original code I posted without changing anything else? @Barmak Shemirani

Comment: I edited the answer. Yes you can call `free(pathCopy)` at the very **end**, but don't call `free(node->str);` like I did in my version. By the way, don't use underscore `_`  as prefix, that's reserved for library function. `my_get_dir` is okay, but not `_getdir`. Also, you don't really need a linked list for this, you can just allocate array of strings, it would be less prone to errors. I am not sure what your requirements are.